# slideToggle on link

Tags: jquery

The script below works fine if 3 and 3.2 are not links but i cant figure out how to get this to work while they are links.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> - Test</title>

  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.js'></script>

<style>
ul{
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0;
margin-left: 0;
font-weight: bold;
}
</style>





<script type='text/javascript'>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#nav ul li:not(:has(li.current))").find("ul").hide().end() // Hide all other ULs
    .click(function(e) {
        if (this == e.target) {
            $(this).children('ul').slideToggle('fast');
        }
    });
});


</script>


</head>
<body>
  <div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">3</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="example.com">3.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">3.2</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="example.com">3.2.1</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">4</a></li>
    </ul>

</div>


</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've cleaned up your code:

HTML:

```
  <div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="example.com">3.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">3.2</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="example.com">3.2.1</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
    </ul>

</div>​
```

css:

```
ul{
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0;
margin-left: 0;
font-weight: bold;
}

ul ul{
    display:none;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#nav ul li a[href="#"]').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).siblings('ul').toggle();
    });
});​
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/PvQVY/

Answer (score 0):

Use *[preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)* to stop the link from being followed:

```
.click(function(e) {
    if (this == e.target) {
        $(this).children('ul').slideToggle('fast');
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: im pretty sure it can just be `e.preventDefault` and not `$(e).`

Comment: Thanks.  If i click the actual 3 link nothing happens.  If i click just of (still the li) it expands so how do i get it to expand when clicking the actual link?

Comment: You could use a conditional with **$(this).attr('href') === undefined** to check whether the click was on a link.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are checking this **this == e.target**, Try this instead

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#nav ul li:not(:has(li.current))").find("ul").hide().end() // Hide all other ULs
     .click(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       $(this).children('ul').slideToggle('fast');
   });
});
```